# PN532 Unable to wait for SPI data

Tags: nfc

I'm following this https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=78966using a PN532 I purchased. When i type in

```
NFC-LIST
```

I get this:

```
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
error   libnfc.driver.pn532_spi   Unable to wait for SPI data. (RX)
pn53x_check_communication: Timeout
error   libnfc.driver.pn532_spi   Unable to wait for SPI data. (RX)
nfc-list: ERROR: Unable to open NFC device: pn532_spi:/dev/spidev0.0:500000
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions you have. I'm using a Raspberry pi and my setup can be found  [image: here]

Comment: same problem here, but on adafruit pn532 breakout board

Comment: exactly the same problem here, same board, same lib.